# Struggle with loops

Tags: arrays, c, loops, while-loop, new-operator

so I am super new to coding and am just following this tutorial series, the first task here is to create a checker for a password which includes upper/lower case, numbers and symbols, I am stuck at the very beginning howerver...so here's a bit of code and my problems:

```
int main()
{    
     int pw[21];
     int pwVUpper = 0;
     int pwnum = 0;

     printf("Please choose a password.\n");
     printf("Make sure it includes at least one number, lower and upper case letter and one of the symbols: !, _, $, -, /.\n");    
     scanf(" %c", pw);

     while((pwnum<=21)){
        if(isupper(pw[pwnum])){
                printf("lol!");
                pwnum++;
        }
     }    
     return 0;
}
```

so this was just the beginning for checking for the upper letter, I wannt to have the loop go through each letter of the "pw" array, and only then print "lol!", if it checks for an upper letter, however, it only ever checks the first letter in the array and only prints "lol!"once, even if the array happens to be with 2 capitals at any point.

I tried to have the array letter number associated with the variable pwnum and as the loop goes on, the variable increases and so the next letter would get checked.

JUST A HEADS UP: from various searching, I have come to see that there are much better solutions to what I am trying to do, but a lot of the keywords presented I have not gone over yet and would like to complete this with only the limited knowledge, as suggested by the tutorial series, I seem to misunderstand loops or something and at this point am really starting to feel brain damaged, probably am huh!

Comment: The `pw` array has 21 elements, indexed 0 - 20.  Trying to access index 21 is out-of-bounds and invokes Undefined Behavior.

Comment: Paying attention to the indentation style (where you put your open and close curly braces) can help you understand the structure of the code. This should help you find the problem.

Comment: Formatting is important to improve readability.  Edited that for you here.

Comment: `pwnum++;` should be outside that code block - as it is the loop will stall when `isupper()` is false.

Comment: `int pw[21];` should be `char pw[21];` and `scanf(" %c", pw);` should be `scanf("%20s", pw);` You also can be checking *uninitialised* array elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the issue

```
 while((pwnum<=21)){
    if(isupper(pw[pwnum])){
            printf("lol!");
            pwnum++;
    }
 }
```

Notice that there are **two** statements inside the curly braces controlled by the `if` statement. Namely, a call to `printf()` and an increment of `pwnum`. This means that you only increment `pwnum` when you print "lol" — when you've found an upper case letter.

Restructure the code like this:

```
 while((pwnum<=21)){
    if(isupper(pw[pwnum])){
            printf("lol!");
    }
    pwnum++;
 }
```

Now the index `pwnum` is incremented whether or not you found an upper case letter. This means that the program will move on to look at the next letter.

**ETA**
It's been pointed out (thanks @ryyker) that the array index also has an off by one problem. You do **not** want to try reading the value of `pw[21]` because in an array of 21 elements, a valid index is from 0 to 20 inclusive. Therefore, you should modify your loop as follows:

```
 while((pwnum<21))...
```

There are other issues with the code as well, but hopefully this gets you past the current problem.

Comment: This is also a really good place for a `for` loop, as opposed to the `while` loop. While `while` will accomplish the goal, and should be understood by any beginner, the `for` loop is also important. In this case: `for (pwnum = 0; pwnum <= 20; pwnum++) { ... }`

Comment: @Chris agreed, but the OP asked for a solution that didn't use unfamiliar keywords, so I've left that out.

Comment: That's why I merely add it as a comment rather than an answer. And they're all unfamiliar... until they aren't. ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tips and the speedy response! I know it is all very newbie and unpolished, but got almost everything done and working now! :)) for loop is much better as I can see indeed, but a lot of the examples were using for loops and I did one with a for loop already, and so I tried to challenge myself with a while loop instead, just to get a better understanding!!

Answer (score 2):

A couple of notes.

If the intent is to create a password string, then the code *[should](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881291/why-is-char-preferred-over-string-for-passwords)* read in a [*C string*](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_strings.htm) before analyzing it.  Change this:

```
int pw[21];
...
scanf(" %c", pw);
```

To this:

```
char pw[21] = {0}; //initialize to all zeros
...
scanf("%20s", pw);//width modifier '20' will prevent overflowing buffer
```

Next remove the index from *inside* the `if(...){...}` statement.  Change this:

```
     while((pwnum<=21)){
         if(isupper(pw[pwnum])){
            printf("lol!");
            pwnum++;
         }
     }
```

To this:

```
     while((pwnum<=20)){//changed to 20 to prevent out-of-bounds
         if(isupper(pw[pwnum])){
            printf("lol!");
         }
         pwnum++;
     }
```

If they are not already in your toolbox, you might also learn about [islower()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_islower.htm) and [isdigit()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_isdigit.htm).  Note, the use of [type casting](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_type_casting.htm) may be necessary as well.  ( eg.  `if(isdigit((int)pw[pwnum]))...` )

Finally, to track the 3 distinctive criteria, number, upper and lower, you could define some boolean variables and a #define...

```
#define PW_GOOD upper&&lower&&digit

bool upper = false;//init all three
bool lower = false;
bool digit = false;
....
if(!upper) {  //enter only once 
    if(isupper(pw[pwnum])){
       upper = true;     
    }//do the same for lower and digit
}
```

later in code test your three criteria with

```
if(PW_GOOD)
{
     printf("lol!");
     ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This has been incredibly helpful! Thanks for the quick response too, know that the code is really rough and unpolished, but now I've almost got it done and working! Really appreciate the extra tips as well and see how they can be incorporated into other stuff as well! :))

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you increment pwnum only if you found an uppercase letter, which is what you wouldn't want. Because, once you find a lowercase letter, it will go to an infinite loop as pwnum won't increase. One solution is to put pwnum outside of the if statement as mentioned by Tim Randall. A better solution is to use for loop instead of while loop in this case. Also note that the maximum index is length-1 so that you are not out of bound.

Other than looping problem, to store a string, you should use a char array instead of an int array. And to input a string, you should use %s instead of %c.

Hope this might help you

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the main problem is that your call to `scanf` is using `%c` for the formatting string, which only reads one character.  It should be `%s`, which reads until you press enter.

Also, there are some other problems as well:

1. The `while` condition should be `pwnum < 21` to avoid overflow, rather than `pwnum<=21`.
2. The type for `pw` should bet `char[]` not `int[]`.  This could cause trouble in some systems.
3. The while loop should search until it reaches the null character `0x0` or `'\0'` , in case the user does not enter 21 characters.  Otherwise, it will continue reading through the uninitialized elements at the end of the array.

Answer (score 0):

1. `scanf(" %c", pw);`: `%c` format specifier is for characters, for a string you can use `scanf("%20[^\n]",pw);`. `%20` is to avoid bufferrun.
2. `while((pwnum<=21)){`: you try to access out of bounds array elements with it. A better method would be to replace this with `while(pw[pwnum]!='\0'){`
3. 

```
if(isupper(pw[pwnum])){
      printf("lol!");
      pwnum++;
}
```

You only increment `pwnum` when an uppercase letter is found and it'll result in an infinite loop if all the letters in `pw` aren't uppercase. Try moving `pwnum++` out of the `if` statement.